# Create Permissions on OneNote

Tags: permissions, microsoft-onenote

I have created a OneNote notebook with procedures hyperlinked to documentation.  I want to share this notebook with the entire team, but only give editor permissions to certain users.  Is this possible? I have not found anything that allows the links to work, but does not allow other users to make changes to the notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A OneNote Notebook takes the permissions of the folder it is placed in.

So, set any permissions (via Group, please) on the folder the Notebook is in, and you'll be set.